# Столбец не существует в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Нужно выделить людей, у которых больше 1 ребенка.

> ОШИБКА: столбец "cnt" не существует Позиция: 134

```
SELECT depart.name, fio, (SELECT count(*) FROM child WHERE child.tabno=emp.tabno) cnt 
FROM emp, depart 
where emp.depnu=depart.id and cnt>1 order by depart.name;
```

А этот код работает (выводит список всех людей и количество их детей):

```
SELECT depart.name, fio, (SELECT count(*) FROM child WHERE child.tabno=emp.tabno) cnt 
FROM emp, depart 
where emp.depnu=depart.id 
order by depart.name;
```

Как убрать из вывода ненужные строки с 0 и 1 ребенком? Что нужно исправить, чтобы заработала верхняя строка?

UPD: cnt выглядит как столбец, как сравнить в ней каждую строку со значением 1?

Comment: Алиасы из списка выборки не доступны в where того же уровня, потому что они появляются уже после того как отработал where. Либо оберните запрос в еще один уровень `select ... from (ваш запрос) A where cnt>1` либо повторите подзапрос целиком (не рекомендуется). либо перенесите таблицу child в основной from, т.е. сделайте вообще без подзапроса и используйте having (рекомендуется)

Comment: @Mike а что должно быть в части having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По порядку выполнения, сначала выполняется `from`, затем `where`, и только после этого `select`, поэтому в `where` он еще не знает, что происходит в `select`, в том числе ваш подзапрос недоступен для него.

2 способа решения проблемы:

1. обернуть в новый запрос

   ```
   select t.*
   from   (SELECT depart.name,
               fio,
               (SELECT count(*) FROM child WHERE child.tabno=emp.tabno) cnt 
           FROM emp, depart 
           where emp.depnu=depart.id 
           order by depart.name) t
   where t.cnt > 1
   ```
2. использовать `having`:

   ```
   SELECT depart.name,
       fio,
       count(child.tabno) cnt 
   FROM emp join depart on emp.depnu=depart.id
       left join child on child.tabno=emp.tabno
   group by depart.name, fio
   having count(child.tabno) > 1
   order by depart.name
   ```

Comment: 2 запрос выдает такую же ошибку

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: В MySQL бы это прокатило, там алиасы доступны в having. НО в postrgesql нельзя использовать алиасы в предложении having

Comment: @Mike не знал, спасибо. С MySQL только работаю на данный момент.